# sql find date between two php date values

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I can't seem to find the answer to my dilemma, I have two php variables

```
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d'); //output 2013-07-29
$twoWeeksAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 weeks')); //output 2013-07-15

$dates = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT attend_date FROM $table WHERE attend_date <= '$todaysDate' AND attend_dateORDER BY date ASC"); //Select all dates between today and two weeks ago
```

when I stick them into my query, I get an error and cannot loop through the result. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Here is the error I have been getting:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: The best thing you can do is tell us what error you get...

Comment: Sorry about that, just realized. I'll post above

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a space between `attend_date` and `ORDER BY`, so this may be causing the error.
In addition to this, your warning may be due to the fact that (possibly) your query is returning `false` so there is no `mysqli_result` to process.
Try running a check like this (after your query):

```
if (!$dates){
    echo "Dates returns false!";
}
else {
    // do whatever you were planning to do, like the mysqli_fetch_array
}
```

or you can try this check also (to see what `$dates` is):

```
var_dump($dates);
```